# How to change play/pause button of MediaController without a VideoView

Tags: android

I am making a mediaplayer which works with both MediaController buttons and proximity sensors. When using the play/pause button of the MediaController the button toggles, but how do I toggle the play/pause icon when using a sensor?

Buttons and the proximity sensor can both play/pause the music. So, suppose a song is playing; the icon is that of "pause" on the MediaController. Now when I use the sensor to pause it, the button should also change. How do I do it? I don't have any `VideoView` so is there any other way to explicitly change it?

Comment: can you post some code you've tried?

Comment: Umm which function in particular.. Cause the code is huge, I have a proximity sensor which uses a sensorEventListener, and i play music using a service

Comment: this is the tutorial i referred to      http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764